# How to get size of collection MongoDB/Drive class in Php

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm a beginner in PHP. My PHP version 7.3 and I cannot use MongoClient class because I have an error. So How can I get the size of the collection MongoDB/Drive class in Php?

```
$m =new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);    
$res = $m->executeQuery("Paper.Papers", $query);

print_r(count(iterator_to_array($res)));
```

My solution is inefficient. Is there a different way?

**UPDATE**

I found alternative way to get size of collection:

```
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["dbstats" => 1]);
$res = $m->executeCommand("Paper", $command);

$stats = current($res->toArray());
```

Then;

```
print_r($stats->objects);
```

**Output :** 6000